# Rails thumbs_up gem vote_exclusively_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm currently using the thumbs_up gem to allow my users to vote on posts and am having an issue with the vote_exclusively_for/against methods.  Here is the gem's github link:  https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up.  The gem works fine with the vote_up and vote_down methods, but when I change it to vote_exclusively_for (which is supposed to replace a previous down vote w/ an up vote), I get the following error in my development log:

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Voteable has already been taken):
 app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:97:in `vote_up'
```

It appears that a method inside the gem is not clearing out the previous vote before initiating the new vote.  Here is my code in the posts_controller:

```
  def vote_up
    @user = current_user
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @user.vote_exclusively_for(@post)
    redirect_to (..)
 end
```

Here is the code from the gem:

```
  def vote_exclusively_for(voteable)
    self.vote(voteable, { :direction => :up, :exclusive => true })
   end

 def vote(voteable, options = {})
    raise ArgumentError, "you must specify :up or :down in order to vote" unless options[:direction] && [:up, :down].include?(options[:direction].to_sym)
    if options[:exclusive]
     self.clear_votes(voteable)
    end
    direction = (options[:direction].to_sym == :up)
    Vote.create!(:vote => direction, :voteable => voteable, :voter => self)
  end

 def clear_votes(voteable)
    Vote.where(
      :voter_id => self.id,
      :voter_type => self.class.name,
      :voteable_id => voteable.id,
      :voteable_type => voteable.class.name
    ).map(&:destroy)
  end
```

I'm not sure why the clear_votes method isn't deleting the previous vote.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this in the console and see if it works or not:

```
user = ... # fetch the right user
post = ... # fetch the right post

Vote.where(
  :voter_id => user.id,
  :voter_type => User,
  :voteable_id => post.id,
  :voteable_type => Post
).map(&:destroy)
```

You can also temporarily edit `clear_votes` and do some logging there to make sure that the `self.class.name` and `voteable.class.name` are referring to the right classes. Also log the `where` method call with a `count` before the map to the destroy command to ensure that it's not returning an empty array.

Comment: I believe you've steered me in the right direction.  I have a single-table inheritance setup for posts so there are 2 different classes of Posts.  I believe the :voteable_type is being set to one of the inherited classes, but I've got it set to the parent class in the Vote table.  It should work with a few tweaks, thanks!